# My regular expression is getting white space after words and shouldn't

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression that is supposed to capture Upper case words.  So if there are one or more words that are all uppercase the regex finds it.  But I also have another regular expression that captures One word all uppercase word.  For some reason the first reg ex is capturing one word all uppercase with a traling white space at the end.  Here is my code.

```
    //This looks for All Cap Words inside parens-completed
    String ucParensRegEx = "\\([A-Z]+\\)";
    regexParser(we, ucParensRegEx);
    //This looks for All Upper case words with two or more letters.- completed
    String twoPlusUCRegEx = "[A-Z][A-Z]+";
    regexParser(we, twoPlusUCRegEx);

    String letNumRegEx = "[A-Z][A-Z0-9][A-Z]+";
    regexParser(we, letNumRegEx);

    //Looks for Uppercase words that start with a number-Completed
    String numLetRegEx = "[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]+";
    regexParser(we, numLetRegEx);

    String upperwhitespaceRegEx = "(\\b[A-Z'][A-Z]+\\b\\s*)+";
    regexParser(we, upperwhitespaceRegEx);

private void regexParser(WordExtractor we, String regex) {
    if (we.getParagraphText() != null) {
        String[] dataArray = we.getParagraphText();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
            String data = dataArray[i].toString();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
            while (m.find()) {
                if (!sequences.contains(data.substring(m.start(), m.end())) && !data.equals("US ") && !data.contains("ARABIC") && !data.contains("ALATEC") && !data.contains("HYPERLINK")) {
                    sequences.add(data.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
                    System.out.println(data.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
                    Acronym acc = new Acronym(data.substring(m.start(), m.end()), data, "", false);
                    newAcList.add(acc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post an example of a string that is matching that you don't expect to match?

Comment: None of your regexes capture a trailing whitespace character, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry I had to add it in...I forgot.  Take a look at the upperwhitespaceRegEx variable definition.

Comment: Yes, that regex ends with `\s*`, which matches white space characters. The `*` is a greedy quantifier, which means it will prefer the longest possible match. If you want the shortest match (so as not to include spaces after the last matched word) you should use the "reluctant" version `*?`

Comment: See I am looking for multiple uppercase words like HAM SANDWICH but on the one word uppercase words like HAM I get HAM and a white space.  So on the one word regex's would that work.

Comment: I still haven't found an answer on this.

Comment: @IanRoberts: If you change `\s*` to `\s*?` it will only match one word at a time.  For example, `FOO BAR` will return `FOO` and `BAR` separately, when the OP clearly wants one match: `FOO BAR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"\\b[A-Z'][A-Z]+(\s+[A-Z'][A-Z]+)*\\b"
```

The interior word boundaries are unnecessary (as `\s[A-Z]` will definitionally have a word boundary between the whitespace and the Upper case letter).  So all you need to do is match an uppercase word, then optionally match a bunch of other uppercase words after it.